# Can brothers who performed separate Maasikas perform Samvatsarika Shraddha Karma together?

Tags: karma, death, sraddha

Can brothers who performed separate Maasikas perform Samvatsarika Shraddha Karma together? They've perfomed Dina karma together and all rituals during the first ten days.